# Terraform - Variable name for CosmosDB

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm using Terraform to create the resources in Azure and have split the files as *main.tf*, *variables.tf* and *terraform.tfvars*

In order to have a standard naming convention, I'm following the process below when naming the resources.

*prefix-environment-resourcename*

**For example**, in *main.tf* I'm creating it as below:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
name     = "${var.prefix}-${var.environment}-${var.resource_group_name}" 
location = "westus"
}
```

The variables will be declared in *variables.tf* and the *terraform.tfvars* will contain

```
prefix = "sample"
environment = "dev"
resource_group_name = "rg"
```

and when the Terraform is executed, I'll get the resource name created as "*sample-dev-rg*"

This will come in handy when I'm creating other resources or deploy the code to other environments. Since I just need to modify the tfvars alone.

**Another example:**

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
  name  = "${var.prefix}-${var.environment_name}-${var.appservice_name}"
}
```

**My issue is:**

- How do I use the logic above for CosmosDb? I need the name in the *main.tf* to be
  created without special characters.
- How do I create something like
  this: sampledevcosmosdbname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Terraform 0.13 and above, you can make use of [regex validation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#custom-validation-rules) for each of the variables that make up your resource names, and ensure that none of them use special/unusual characters. Here's an example `prefix` variable that can only use A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and `-` characters:

```
variable "prefix" {
  type        = string
  description = "Prefix ID"

  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("^[A-Za-z0-9-]*$", var.prefix))
    error_message = "The prefix cannot use special characters."
  }
}
```

To create something like `sampledevcosmosdbname` (`prefix`, `environment`, `dbname`), you can just place several interpolations next to one another like so - no separation is needed:

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_sql_database" "example" {
   ...
   name = "${var.prefix}${var.environment}${var.dbname}"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adil. Both the responses worked like a charm!! The only minor change I had to do was add a period at the end of the error message, otherwise the following error shows up "Validation error message must be at least one full English sentence starting
with an uppercase letter and ending with a period or question mark."

Comment: Thanks @Scorpio! Edited my answer to add the period as well.